# When ld can't find symbol _start, what does it default to?

Tags: ld

When running ld I get the warning 'cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000000010001000'. There is an ongoing investigation where it is, probably involving passing an elaborate "wtf?" to the vendor responsible for the build env, but please ignore that, nothing you can do.

My question however is what ld defaults to, and what behavior to expect. Apparently the condition is not serious enough for ld to return with error, but since it is classified a warning I'm guessing something might go wrong... or it may not?

Comment: What is this related to?

Comment: @user2818430 The linker ld